# Unable to play the pcm file recorded using AudioRecord in Android

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I am developing an Android app. In my app I need to record audio using AudionRecord and need to play it. But throwing error when play the recorded pcm file. The main problem is I cannot log know the error as well because I have to test on real device and cannot run on emulator. Because when I run on emulator and record, my application crash.

This is my activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Boolean recording;
    private Thread recordingThread = null;
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
    short[] audioData;


    private Button btnPlay,btnStop,btnRecord;
    private String outputFile = null;
    //outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/recording.3gp";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        initViews();
        setUpViews();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {

    }

    private void initViews()
    {
        btnPlay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
        btnRecord = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_record);
        btnStop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
    }

    private void setUpViews()
    {
        btnRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startRecord();
            }
        });

        btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                recording = false;
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                playRecord();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startRecord(){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        try {
            file.createNewFile();

            OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

            final int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

            final AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    minBufferSize);

            audioRecord.startRecording();

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Recording",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    while(recording){
                        int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);
                        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
                            try{
                                dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
                            }
                            catch (IOException e)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, "AudioRecorder Thread");

            audioRecord.stop();
            dataOutputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void playRecord(){

        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.pcm");

        int shortSizeInBytes = Short.SIZE/Byte.SIZE;

        int bufferSizeInBytes = (int)(file.length()/shortSizeInBytes);
        short[] audioData = new short[bufferSizeInBytes];

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(bufferedInputStream);

            int i = 0;
            while(dataInputStream.available() > 0){
                audioData[i] = dataInputStream.readShort();
                i++;
            }

            dataInputStream.close();

            AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                    11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
                    bufferSizeInBytes,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            audioTrack.play();
            audioTrack.write(audioData, 0, bufferSizeInBytes);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is with playing the recorded pcm. When I click play button, application throws fatal error and stopped. I cannot log the error as well. The pcm file really exists at the defined path as well. What is wrong with my code? Why can it not play?

As you can see below, pcm file created successfully after recording

[image]

Comment: `audioRecord.startRecording();` ... few CPU cycles later ... `audioRecord.stop();` ... `recordingThread`  is never started ... and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the Logcat, it is hard to figure the issue in your code. Take a look at this working code on 'How to play pcm files using AudioTrack':

```
private void PlayAudioFileViaAudioTrack(String filePath) throws IOException
{
// We keep temporarily filePath globally as we have only two sample sounds now..
if (filePath==null)
return;

int intSize = android.media.AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT); 

AudioTrack at = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 44100, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO,
AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, intSize, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM); 


if (at==null){ 
Log.d("TCAudio", "audio track is not initialised ");
return; 
}

int count = 512 * 1024; // 512 kb
//Reading the file..
byte[] byteData = null; 
File file = null; 
file = new File(filePath);

byteData = new byte[(int)count];
FileInputStream in = null;
try {
in = new FileInputStream( file );

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

int bytesread = 0, ret = 0;
int size = (int) file.length();
at.play();
while (bytesread < size) { 
   ret = in.read( byteData,0, count); 
   if (ret != -1) { // Write the byte array to the track 
    at.write(byteData,0, ret); 
    bytesread += ret; 
    } 

    else break; 
} 
    in.close();    
    at.stop(); 
    at.release(); 
}
```

code from http://jongladwin.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/android-play-pcmwav-audio-buffer-using.html